# TextInput EditText android is not working or cannot insert any value

Tags: android

I have a fragment that actually simple inputting text value into editText. But I can't input any text to my second EditText. It keeps not giving any value. Please help me with what is actually the problem. So the way working is First showing the first EditText in the first Relative Layout, and then open the second relative layout with the 2nd EditText, and then the third RelativeLayout with the EditText. The First and Third is working fine. But the second keeps not giving any value. Although I put validation it keeps saying me to input text which is I did!???? Please help me thank you.

```
private void initUI(View view) {

    relativeLayout_1 = view.findViewById(R.id.rl_1);
    relativeLayout_2 = view.findViewById(R.id.rl_2);
    relativeLayout_3 = view.findViewById(R.id.rl_3);

    relativeLayout_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    civ1 = view.findViewById(R.id.iv_next);
    civ2 = view.findViewById(R.id.iv_next2);
    civ3 = view.findViewById(R.id.iv_next3);

    txtEmail = view.findViewById(R.id.input_email);
    txtName = view.findViewById(R.id.input_username);
    txtPassword = view.findViewById(R.id.input_password);

    tv_hello = view.findViewById(R.id.text_hello);

    civ1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            relativeLayout_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            email = txtEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            createName(email);
        }
    });

}

private void createName(String email) {

    //relativeLayout_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    relativeLayout_1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    tv_hello.setText("Hello " + email);

       //Problem is in here
        userName = txtName.getText().toString().trim();

        civ2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                relativeLayout_3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                createPassword(email, userName);

            }
        });
}

private void createPassword(String email, String username) {


    relativeLayout_2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    txtPassword.setText(name);

    password = txtPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    civ3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final String URL = Config.APP_API_URL + Config.POST_USER_REGISTER;
            Utils.psLog(URL);

            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("username", username);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);
            params.put("about_me", "");
            doSubmit(URL, params);

 ///RESULT username is null / keep empty
        }
    });

}


 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">



<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/space_11"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<!--INSERT EMAIL-->

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rl_1"
    android:visibility="gone">

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_jemane"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/space_3"
    android:src="@drawable/jemane_trans"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/colorSweetGreenDark"
    app:civ_circle_background_color="@color/colorSpotLightYellow"
    app:civ_border_width="4dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/iv_jemane"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/space_3"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="@string/splash2_email"
    android:textColor="@color/colorSweetGreenDarkest"
    android:textSize="@dimen/headline2"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInput"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/text_home"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/space_3"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/space_3">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/input_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/space_10"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorSweetGreenDark">

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>
   </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView 
    android:id="@+id/iv_next"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
   android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textInput"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/space_3"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_white_24dp"
    app:civ_border_color="#e8e8e8"
    app:civ_circle_background_color="@color/colorSweetGreenDarkest"
    app:civ_border_width="1dp" />
  </RelativeLayout>

  <!-- CREATE NAME-->
   <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_jemane2"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/space_3"
        android:src="@drawable/jemane_trans"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/colorSweetGreenDark"
        app:civ_circle_background_color="@color/colorSpotLightYellow"
        app:civ_border_width="4dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_hello"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iv_jemane2"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/space_3"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="@string/splash2_name1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorSweetGreenDarkest"
        android:textSize="@dimen/headline2"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_home2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_hello"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/space_3"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="@string/splash2_name2"
        android:textColor="@color/colorSweetGreenDarkest"
        android:textSize="@dimen/headline2"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInput2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_home2"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/space_3"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/space_3">

        <!--KEEP EMPTY NO VALUE-->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/input_username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/space_10"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorSweetGreenDark">

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_next2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textInput2"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/space_3"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_white_24dp"
        app:civ_border_color="#e8e8e8"
        app:civ_circle_background_color="@color/colorSweetGreenDarkest"
        app:civ_border_width="1dp" />


</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone">


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView 
        android:id="@+id/iv_jemane3"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/space_3"
        android:src="@drawable/jemane_trans"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/colorSweetGreenDark"
        app:civ_circle_background_color="@color/colorSpotLightYellow"
        app:civ_border_width="4dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_home3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iv_jemane3"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/space_3"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="@string/splash3_name1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorSweetGreenDarkest"
        android:textSize="@dimen/headline2"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_createPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_home3"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/space_3"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="@string/splash3_name3"
        android:textColor="@color/colorSweetGreenDarkest"
        android:textSize="@dimen/headline2"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInput3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_createPassword"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/space_3"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/space_3">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/input_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/space_10"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorSweetGreenDark">

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView 
        android:id="@+id/iv_next3"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textInput3"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/space_3"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_white_24dp"
        app:civ_border_color="#e8e8e8"
        app:civ_circle_background_color="@color/colorSweetGreenDarkest"
        app:civ_border_width="1dp" />


</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing this

```
civ2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                relativeLayout_3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                userName = txtName.getText().toString().trim();
                createPassword(email, userName);

            }
        });
```